# Keyboard hides EditText content

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have two edit text aligned vertically to each other the problem is when the keyboard appeared it hides the edit texts content.I want them to be scrolled up when the keyboard appears.I know it's a famous problem but tried more than a way but with no success.I wrapped the whole layout in a ScrollView and added to the mainfest **adjustPan** also tried **adjustResize|stateHidden** but with no success.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and it didn't work here's my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/loginpage">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1200">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="288">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="288">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"></LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_edit_text_padding_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_edit_text_padding_right"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:textDirection="ltr"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_edit_text_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_edit_text_padding_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_edit_text_padding_right"
                android:password="true"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_edit_text_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using framelayout as a parent ? did you tried using scrollview as a parent ? and you are giving huge size to edittexts what about something like wrap_content ?

Comment: When I use scrollview as a parent the view is stretched which I don''t want and why using weights it's a design issue I didn't copy the whole xml only the important parts.

Comment: the view can be fixed and there are many issues in your xml. it's not the complete code so i fixed these two edittexts on top and they appear to working fine on my side.

Comment: Are you using windowFullscreen  in your theme?

Comment: No I'm not using it.

Comment: I was using FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS when removed it worked 
you saved my day by your hint.